# How to add custom Classloader to ObjectMapper?

Tags: json, classloader, jackson

Is there any way to instruct Jackson 2 ObjectMapper to use custom Classloader to deserialize JSON strings?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution:

```
ClassLoader myClassLoader = ...        

ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
TypeFactory tf = TypeFactory.defaultInstance()
                            .withClassLoader(myClassLoader);
om.setTypeFactory(tf);
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Jackson Wiki for [Modules](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeatureModules), a Jackson Module can be used to create custom serialization / deserialization. While the wiki talks about what they can do

> Add custom serializers and deserializers
>
> Add mix-in annotations
>
> Override or add AnnotationIntrospector
>
> Access SerializationConfig and DeserializationConfig settings.

It is pretty light on details, just giving a very basic example. The [Module JavaDoc](http://fasterxml.github.com/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/Module.html) is light on details as well. Fortunately the wiki also has a [list of existing Jackson Modules](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonModuleProjects) on GitHub, which is more helpful as examples if you need to create your own Module from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

To preserve the existing `TypeMapper`, you might want to do something like this (this is Scala, but same pattern works in Java), where you adjust the current type factory.

```
  def updateClassLoader(cl: ClassLoader): Unit = {
    objectMapper.setTypeFactory(objectMapper.getTypeFactory.withClassLoader(cl))
  }
```

This will preserve cached type data from possible prior configuration calls like this:

```
mapper.registerModule(new Jdk8Module)
      .registerModule(new JavaTimeModule)
      .registerModule(new DefaultScalaModule)
```